# Find out whether item was dropped somewhere it shouldnt be dropped

Tags: wpf

I’ve run into a problem and can’t find simple solution to it. I’ve got two listboxes, and a drag and drop between them. It works just fine, but I’m using a custom cursor (I’m taking a visual copy of the item I am dragging), on a release I just remove that custom cursor. The problem I have is that if I drop it somewhere outside of the drop zone, then I can’t create that custom cursor again, until GC collects the old one.

Here is my code

```
private void OnGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cursor == null)
        {
            var dragSource = sender as ASLDDListBox;
            var container = dragSource.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(communication) as ListBoxItem;
            if (container != null)
            {
                cursor = CursorHelper.CreateCursor(container, EnumInternetListBox.All);
                e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
                Mouse.SetCursor(cursor);
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

private void ListBoxOnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
            cursor = null;
}
```

So GiveFeedback runs all the time during the dragg, therefore I make sure I create the cursor once, otherwise I get an exception after about 100times. The problem is if I don’t drop it on that listbox, I don’t get to null that cursor. I could check for the drop on the usercontrol, but this user control is in zillion other user controls. Is there any event that is fired on drop regardless where the drop was?

Hopefully this makes sense to somebody ;)

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you keep your own private reference, and null that reference in the case where it *does* drop in the right place -- and then when it's time to create a new one, just check that private reference. if it's not null, zap it. Not the greatest thing, but it ought to work, since you know that if the user's dragging something new, he must have dropped the old thing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hi, great so simple and works :) I was overthinking it, but it makes perfect sense. If you move your comment to answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Answer submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is this:

I'd keep my own private reference in a field, and null that reference in the case where it does drop in the right place -- and then when it's time to create a new one, just check that private reference. if it's not null, zap it.

Not the greatest thing, but it ought to work, since you know that if the user's dragging something new, he must have dropped the old thing.